# Magento uses <h1> for the logo on EVERY page - Duplicate h1 tags

Tags: magento-1, theme, header, meta-tags, tags

I used `onpage.org` for an SEO analysis and it told me I have a lot of pages with double h1 tags on my Magento shop. 
I checked this and **it seems my logo is h1 on every page**, probably due to the theme, while this should only be on the home page.

I have searched in `app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/page/html/header.phtml` and found a reference to the h1 tag on the logo, but am not sure what to do, delete this entire code?

```
<div class="logo-block">
      <?php if ($logoStatus == 0): ?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
     <?php else:?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $logoAlt; ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $logoAlt; ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.$logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logoAlt; ?>" /></a></h1>
     <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Use template path hints on a development box to see which PHTML file is being loaded instead of the default (unless the default file was edited, which is possible too).

Answer (score 1):

Default Magento templates DO NOT set `<h1>` on the logo by default you can see in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml` :

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
<?php else:?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
<?php endif?>
```

So I suggest you update your code with the following:

```
<div class="logo-block">
     <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
      <?php if ($logoStatus == 0): ?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
     <?php else:?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $logoAlt; ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $logoAlt; ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.$logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logoAlt; ?>" /></a></h1>
     <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?php if ($logoStatus == 0): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
     <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $logoAlt; ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $logoAlt; ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.$logo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $logoAlt; ?>" /></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems some (bought) themes do this. So I just add this code? Sorry, don't know much/anything about coding.

Comment: @isabelle yeah just replace the code you posted with the code I posted